# NSOutlineView: how to tick all selected checkbox with a click?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

When I select multiple rows in a NSOutlineView I would like to click on the checkbox of just one row and having selected all checkboxes.

Now, If I click on one checkbox only the clicked row row remains selected and only such checkbox is ticked.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to write a handler for the checkbox action, that enumerated all the selected rows in the NSOutlineView, using selectedRowIndexes, then use those indexes in a loop to locate and setChecked the checkboxes.

> http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSTableView